# Google sheets api not recognizing all cells correctly

Tags: python, cell, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to make a script to make a rating based on the cells and based on the length of the value of each cell that I chose. The problem is that when I use this code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# get the instance of the Spreadsheet
sheet = client.open('Copy of Event Organizer')

# get the first sheet of the Spreadsheet
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(3)

words = ["C4", "C5", "C7", "C9", "C11", "C13", "C15", "C17", "C19", "C21", "C23", "C25"]
values = [1012, 12317, 1120, 1345, 134, 1120, 1420, 5, 531, 220, 15, 2354]

len_list = []
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    try:
        len_list.append(len(sheet_instance.acell(word).value))

    except:
        len_list.append(0)
    len_list[i] = len_list[i] * values[i]

print(len_list)
print(sum(len_list))
sheet_instance.update_acell("C29", sum(len_list))
```

The code for some reason tells me that the first cell (C4) is empty even when it is not, and so the calculation becomes wrong. Why does that happen? And sometimes this also happens to other cells.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `The code for some reason tells me that the first cell (C4) is empty even when it is not, and so the calculation becomes wrong.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: `for i, word in enumerate(words):` can be made more readable by using `for value, word in zip(values, words):`. Also there is no need append to `len_list` only to modify it subsequently

Comment: @Tanaike I mean like there is the cell C4, when I run my app, the script doesn't recognize that C4 has a value.

Comment: @JiWei what do you mean? please help me

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I mean like there is the cell C4, when I run my app, the script doesn't recognize that C4 has a value.`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike in cell C4 there is data

Comment: and it's not showing when I'm pulling it from sheets